# How to select all points within a circle in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point, sql, circle

I have set of points in a PostGIS Table (Type Geometry).

Now, I need to filter points that lie in a circle with a center (C) and radius (R)!

I expect C to be of type Point or Coordinates..  R to be in Meters!

```
SELECT * FROM my_points
    WHERE ST_Within(point, ...)
```

However, I don't know how to complete it..

How can I exactly measure C and R?

Answer (score 5):

You actually want [ST_DWITHIN](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) - take care R is assumed to be in SRID units unless you are using geographies instead of geometries.

```
select * from my_points where ST_DWITHIN(my_points.point,c,r);
```

Comment: what about C.. how should I mention it?

Comment: usually ST_GeomFromText()

Comment: use `ST_MakePoint(x, y)` for c

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ST_Point_Inside_Circle](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point_Inside_Circle.html) function. The function is self explainained :

`boolean ST_Point_Inside_Circle(geometry a_point, float center_x, float center_y, float radius);`

> The syntax for this functions is
>   point_inside_circle(geometry,circle_center_x,circle_center_y,radius).
>   Returns the **true if the geometry is a point and is inside the circle**.
>
> Returns false otherwise.

Here's an example:

```
 select * from TABLE as A where ST_Point_Inside_Circle(a.geom,x,y,R); 
  -- where the x,y is the center of your circle thus C(x,y). R is the Radius. 
  --The SRID must be in something that uses meters.
```

I haven't seen the actual function yet, but I have a hunch that it creates a buffer zone  for each point and checks if it's inside or not, and returns T/F accordingly.

Another way is with a **subquery**: You create in your SQ your circle, and then check each point of yours if it is inside or not.

```
with MyCircle as (select ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y),SRID, R) as geom) 
-- Circle centered at C(x,y), Radius R. 
-- Use the same srid as your points in your table. 
select * from TABLE as A where st_intersects(MyCircle.geom,a.geom);
```

Comment: Doing an actual buffer is generally always discouraged, since  it is actually more complicated and expensive than one would think. It is *always* much cheaper to compare distances between points. `ST_Point_Inside_Circle` uses a C function to determine the distance from a point to a circle with a centre and radius, [as shown here](http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.2/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_a3f378614c49d2169f066a0b906d93034.html#a3f378614c49d2169f066a0b906d93034).

Comment: There is a missing ) in the second example just before "as geom", I couldn't add it because edits must be 6 characters at least!